# Why doesn't Java treat explicit division by zero as a compile-time exception?

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions, arithmeticexception

Why is explicit division By zero not considered as compile time exception in JAVA ?

Example :

int x =9;
int y = (int)x/0;

Shouldnt compiler notify me about it ?

I tried running the same and finding answers to it , I am not convinced that why is that a checked exception. Divinding by another variable has to be runtime , agreed. But explicit division by ) shoukd be at compile time.

Comment: Good question. This could definitely be something interesting. At least as a warning.

Comment: Well, there are IntelliJ inspections for that, and you can set it to error if you like. And SonarLint is also generating a warning for it. I'm sure that spotbugs and errorprone also detect that.

Comment: I guess it is a very naive bug to write hence it will always fail and that is why it is not handled by the compiler.